# Beam/Dataflow PubsubIO: When is default timestamp assigned?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

If timestamp attribute is not assigned at publish time or read time, what timestamp is used for windowing? [Documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html) states that first time system sees each record. Is this system dataflow topology or Pub/Sub?

> If timestampAttribute is not provided, the system will generate record
>   timestamps the first time it sees each record. All windowing will be
>   done relative to these timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp assigned to messages when you don't specify a timestamp attribute is the "publishTime" set on the pubsub message.

See: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/50d0760faf01bdcdea988157a6b732bb448ba4b8/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubJsonClient.java#L178